# Calling a Google Map function in webpage not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have the following function in the `<head>` of a webpage:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function(){
    function googmap(){

    var marker;
    var circle;
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var latit = 5;
    var longi = 6;
    var search_range =  2;

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
centre: new google.maps.LatLng(latit, longi),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
zoom: 6
});

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(latit, longi),
map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
return function() {
infowindow.setContent(latit);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
})(marker, i));

    }
    });
    </script>
```

I call this function using:

```
<body onLoad="googmap()">
```

However in the javascript console it is telling me that the function `googmap()` is not defined. Im sure this issue is to do with scope, etc or the way ive defined the function is wrong, but im very new to JavaScript so I cant troubleshoot it myself - any help would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call "onLoad='googmap()'" here because you already do the function in jquery document.ready.

All you need to do here is change the script in:
(leave out the rule 'function googmap() {' and the matching closing '}')

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var marker;
var circle;
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var latit = 5;
var longi = 6;
var search_range =  2;

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
centre: new google.maps.LatLng(latit, longi),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
zoom: 6
});

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(latit, longi),
map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
return function() {
infowindow.setContent(latit);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
})(marker, i));
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: brilliant, thankyou! So am I right in thinking because the googmap() function was inside the 'anonymous' function, the main webpage didnt think it was defined? Also, is using jquery document.ready a good way of calling functions you want to run automatically?

Comment: Indeed! The document.ready is triggered when the page is loaded, so all the code here will be triggered. If you want to call multiple functions in here, you can just call the functionname 'googmap(); inside the document.ready, together with many other functions. You then just have to declare those functions outside of the document.ready tags.

Answer (score 0):

You are right when you say that googmap is not defined due to scope. Since the function is created inside an anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

it doesn't exist outside it. Add googmap(); to the end of the anonymous function.